# Is the Poisson distribution a special case of exponential distribution?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, probability, distributions

I am getting confused .How can a Poisson be a special case of exponential distribution?

Comment: It isn't. It's a member of an [exponential *family*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family), which is a different thing.

Comment: They are also connected through a Poisson *process*: if the gaps between events has an exponential distribution then the number of events in a time interval has a Poisson distribution. This is why the complementary CDF of an exponential distribution looks similar to the probability that a Poisson random variable is $0$.  A key difference between them is that an exponential distribution is continuous while a Poisson distribution is discrete and can only take non-negative integer values.